# Weird HighCharts Gantt Navigator rendering

Tags: highcharts, gantt-chart

Having some issues with the rendering of the navigator in gantt chart.

First on initial rendering it shows a range from like 1970 to 2017 (end date in this chart)
[image]
Then if I collapse a node, then it sets its date range correctly and the range stays correct thereafter.
[image]

Note that I added min and max values to the xAxis just to make sure that the range was fully set.

So that is correct but the content isn't as expected, where I'm trying to emulate the base example and show a mini gantt. My content is:

[image]

I originally had a yAxis like in the example but getting essentially the same results.

Comment: The first part about the weird rendering seems to be caused by unsorted data as I noticed some error 15 in the console. See fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/alpic80/15nwydo3/". This happens in both treegrid or simple list. IMHO this is an issue since the date range of item isn't always sorted. For example in list/category mode we offer to list as is, sort by name, duration or by time.

Comment: You have found the error and you know what is the problem, so please fix (sort correctly) the data and if the problem will be still visible - add a live demo for the problem.

Comment: The was not the error and it was related to parent task without values for which I opened an issue.

Comment: There is an error in the browser console when viewing your demo - it should be resolved as explained in the error link, please check if resolving the error will resolve your problem and if not please update the demo to the one without the errors. If you have opened an issue (on GitHub?) then please share the link.

Comment: Issue is: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/12809

For those who might be interested the issue with the weird navigator content was due to the fact that the series was coded as an array, like regular series, instead of a single instance.